# My program freeze, before reading from NetworkStream

Tags: c#, tcp, networkstream

Hello I am a student and I'm not used to c# yet. I am writing a program with server and client, which are connected with socket. I am trying to implement a way to read from stream, when data is available, with while loop. I can avoid chrashing if I show message with MessageBox.Show() before reading/writing stream. I don't know why program without displayed message isn't working...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    const int port = 22222;
    const string ip = "127.0.0.1";
    IPAddress ipServer = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
    TcpListener server = null;
    TcpClient client = null;
    Thread thServer = null;
    Thread thClient = null;
    NetworkStream dataStream = null;
    const int a = 11;
    const int n = 251;
    string receivedMessage = "";
    bool? izbira = null;



    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        thServer = new Thread(new ThreadStart(startServer));
        thServer.IsBackground = true;
        thServer.Start();    
    }

    void startServer() {

        server = new TcpListener(ipServer, port);
        server.Start();
        textBox4.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox4.AppendText("Strežnik: zagnan na: IP: " + ip + ", port:" + port)));
        client = new TcpClient();
        client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
        NetworkStream dataStream = client.GetStream();
        textBox4.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox4.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + "Strežnik: Sprejet nov uporabnik")));
        if (izbira == true)
        {
            byte[] message = new byte[1024];
            if(dataStream.DataAvailable)
                dataStream.Read(message, 0, message.Length);
            receivedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message);
            textBox4.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox4.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + "Strežnik: Dobil sem sporočilo: " + receivedMessage)));

            message = new byte[1024];
            message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("drugo sporocilo!");
            dataStream.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
        }
        else {
            byte[] message = new byte[1024];
            message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("serbus");
            dataStream.Write(message, 0, message.Length);


        }

    }

    void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (izbira == null) {
            textBox4.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox4.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + "Izbrati morate ali boste datoteko prenesli ali poslali!")));
            return;
        }
        this.button1.Enabled = false;
        client = new TcpClient();
        IPAddress insertedIp = IPAddress.Parse(textBox1.Text);

        client.Connect(insertedIp, Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text));
        dataStream = client.GetStream();


        if (izbira == true)
        {
            byte[] message = new byte[1024];
            message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hejj");

            dataStream.Write(message, 0, message.Length);

            message = new byte[1024];

            MessageBox.Show("");
            while (true)
            {
                if (dataStream.DataAvailable)
                {

                    dataStream.Read(message, 0, message.Length);
                    break;
                }
            }

            receivedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message);
            textBox4.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox4.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + "Strežnik: Dobil sem sporočilo: " + receivedMessage)));
        }
        else {

            byte[] message = new byte[1024];
            MessageBox.Show("Serbus");
            while (true)
            {
                if (dataStream.DataAvailable)
                {

                    dataStream.Read(message, 0, message.Length);
                  break;
                }

            }
            receivedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message);
            textBox4.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox4.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + "Strežnik: Dobil sem sporočilo: " + receivedMessage)));
        }
    }

    void buttonUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        izbira = true;
        this.buttonDownload.Enabled = false;
    }
    void buttonDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        izbira = false;
        this.buttonUpload.Enabled = false;
        this.button2.Text = "Prenesi";
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please provide with all relative code and explain how you program is not working.

Answer (score -2):

Now this is mostly guessing, as we barely have enough code to say anything for certain:

What about the JiT Compiler?

One of it's purposes is dead code detection. It cuts out code it predicts will not have an effect. Unfortunately, it is still only a computer programm, so false positives happen. For example, trying to force a OOM Exception for x32 Framework installations, I had to go out of my way to *not* have the code cut out by the JiT:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace OOM_32_forced
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //each short is 2 byte big, Int32.MaxValue is 2^31.
            //So this will require a bit above 2^32 byte, or 2 GiB
            short[] Array = new short[Int32.MaxValue];

            /*need to actually access that array
            Otherwise JIT compiler and optimisations will just skip
            the array definition and creation */
            foreach (short value in Array)
                Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

A MessageBox will prevent this whole function from being cut out as dead code. Outputting something towards the user is alwasy asumed to "have a effect". However seperate parts of it are still eligible for dead code detection.

Unforunately you have not provided us with a minimal, complete verifyable example. So we can not really help you figure it out any further.

Comment: I bet this is absolutely not related to question... OP's program get killed by Windows due to the fact it stopped handling messages while stuck in reading loop... Not clear why OP is using synchronous code - it's 2019 outside last time I checked and async reading is all the rage...